# Time taken by all the methods used in my application?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have been given with library called xyz.jar, which performs certain job.This jar has many other methods too.All these methods are used at various places in our applications.This library has exposed some interfaces to client. If I want to print the time taken by all the methods used in my application what should i do??

Calculating time for individual methods is easy but to to calculate the time of execution of all methods what approach should i follow?

Comment: You know that the time taken will vary each time you calculate it . right?

Comment: What approaches have you considered, what research have you done, and what caused you to reject those approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) library such as Spring or AspectJ to measure the times taken by the function calls. This way you don't have to modify the existing code and entangle it with the measurement functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to measure time of methods or functions is to make a special benchmark or testing program where you call all those functions multiple times (usually more than 1000, not just like 5 or 10) and then compute the average times.
If you insist on doing this inline somehow, just use a special testing class that will gather the info about all those function calls.